# проблема со .split строки

Tags: java

Задача: В заданной строке поменять первое и последнее слово.

Мой код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class kakoe-to_zadanie {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        String Str = str.nextLine();
        stringSplit(Str);          //<-------------- чтобы по этой строке вывелся результат программы

    }

    static void stringSplit(String Str) {
        String[] result = Str.split(" ");
        String swapWords = result[0];
        result[0] = result[result.length - 1];
        result[result.length - 1] = swapWords;
        return;         //<--------------------------- что прописать в этой строке ? 
    }
}
```

Вопрос: Я все еще пока не пойму либо как правильно инициализировать программу, либо как передать что-то из одного метода в другой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ...
    System.out.println(stringSplit(Str));
}

static String stringSplit(String Str) {
    String[] result = Str.split(" ");
    String swapWords = result[0];
    result[0] = result[result.length - 1];
    result[result.length - 1] = swapWords;
    return String.join(" ", result);
}
```

Comment: Скажите, почему в String.join(" ", result), мы не возвращаем какую-то именную переменную, а именно String? Для меня это выглядит так, будто какая-то из ниоткуда, даже не объявленная, переменная String.

Comment: @Eugene Здесь `String` это класс, статический метод которого `join`, мы вызываем.